# Aw snap in Google Chrome when interactive line chart using nvd3 + angular library

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, d3.js, nvd3.js

I create 4 line chart such as real time line chart using angular.js and nvd3.js.

After 30 minute, my Chrome browser show Aw Snap.

In Mozilla Firefox, it is run normally

`index.html` likes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/v1.0.4/dist/angular-nvd3.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>

    <nvd3 options="options1" data="data"></nvd3>
    <nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>

    <nvd3 options="options1" data="data"></nvd3>


  </body>

</html>
```

And `app.js`

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['nvd3'])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'lineChart',
            height: 180,
            margin : {
                top: 20,
                right: 20,
                bottom: 40,
                left: 55
            },
            x: function(d){ return d.x; },
            y: function(d){ return d.y; },
            useInteractiveGuideline: true,
            duration: 500,    
            yAxis: {
                tickFormat: function(d){
                   return d3.format('.01f')(d);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.options1 = angular.copy($scope.options);
    $scope.options1.chart.duration = 0;
    $scope.options1.chart.yDomain = [-1,1];

    $scope.data = [{ values: [], key: 'Random Walk' }];

    $scope.run = true;

    var x = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        if (!$scope.run) return;
        $scope.data[0].values.push({ x: x,  y: Math.random() - 0.5});
      if ($scope.data[0].values.length > 200) $scope.data[0].values.shift();
        x++;

      $scope.$apply(); // update both chart
    }, 500);        
});
```

Maybe crash by performance memory. Anyone can help me or give me some idea

Comment: I know you've said you're sure, but have you used the inspection tools found under 'Profiles' in Chrome Developer Tools (press F12) to test for a memory leak?

Comment: Thank for comment, I re-checked

Comment: `setInterval` is problematic for this use case.  My guess is you are triggering redraws while redraws are occurring.  I would use a `setTimeout ` delayed 500 ms after the redraw finishes.

Answer (score 1):

By default, angular directive uses a quite expensive `$watch` procedure for tracking data, and this can eventually lead to memory leak.

To turn it off, you can add `{deepWatchDataDepth: 0}` or `{deepWatchData: false}` config attribute. After that the chart will not update automatically if data changes, and we have to update the chart manually. To do this we use directive `api` attribute.

```
<nvd3 options="options" data="data" api="api" config="{deepWatchDataDepth: 0}"></nvd3>
```

And when the data changes we just update the chart

```
$scope.api.update()
```

Try [updated demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/h0fS0DYU5kO6IRWkMDMw?p=preview)

Also you can read more about attributes and use cases in the [docs](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/quickstart)

Don't know if this answer helps you.

Comment: Thanks for support, but `$scope.api.update()` don't solve this defect. Maybe depend on `options `, I ma not sure

Comment: Cool. And does it solve the issue with default directive configuration, with `$watch`?